# Delete rows between NaN and a change in the column value

Tags: python, pandas, delete-row

I am stuck on a problem which looks simple but for which I cannot find a proper solution.

Consider a given Pandas dataframe `df`, composed by multiple columns A1,A2, etc., and let `Ai` be one of its column filled for example as follows:

| Ai |
| --- |
| 25 |
| 30 |
| 30 |
| NaN |
| 12 |
| 15 |
| 15 |
| NaN |

I would like to delete all the rows in `df` for which `Ai` values are between NaN and a "further change" in its value, so that my output (for column `Ai`) would be:

| Ai |
| --- |
| 25 |
| NaN |
| 12 |
| NaN |

Any idea on how to do so would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you describe in a more detail what you mean by 'between NaN and a "further change" in its value'? Based on your output it looks like you are deleting rows with a duplicated value.

Comment: Sure, sorry for being vague. I have a dataset with many missing values in principle, that I backfilled according to certain conditions. In the output there are therefore many duplicated values, but I want to delete the rows that are between a NaN and another value in column `Ai`. They are not necessarily duplicated (consider for instance the sequence 30,26,NaN; where I would like to delete 26 only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### update

Similar to the previous solution but with a filter per group to keep the early duplicates

```
m = df['Ai'].isna()
df.loc[((m|m.shift(fill_value=True))
        .groupby(df['Ai'].ne(df['Ai'].shift()).cumsum())
        .filter(lambda d: d.sum()>0).index
       )]
```

output:

```
     Ai
0  25.0
1  25.0
2  25.0
5   NaN
6  30.0
7  30.0
9   NaN
```

#### original answer

This is equivalent to selecting the NaNs and line below. You could use a mask:

```
m = df['Ai'].isna()
df[m|m.shift(fill_value=True)]
```

Output:

```
     Ai
0  25.0
3   NaN
4  12.0
7   NaN
```

Comment: In the toy example that I provided yes, but there might be in principle multiple lines that I would like to keep. For example, in the following: `25,25,25,30,30,NaN,30,30,32, NaN`, I would like to delete only the first two 30 and 32.

Comment: @Qwerty992 check the update